# PHP Imagick dont work with PDF files in Laravel 8, simple ImagickException

Tags: laravel, pdf, xampp, imagick, php-8

I try to use first time Imagick to convert pdf files to images and it dont work for me.
When i try use Imagick with images files, its ok and working fine, problem is with PDF files.

**My test php controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Imagick;
class NewspaperController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @throws \ImagickException
     */
    public function show()
    {
        $imgExt = new Imagick();

        $imgExt->readImage(public_path('storage/uploads/test.pdf'));

       $imgExt->writeImages(public_path('storage/uploads/pdf_image_doc.jpg'), false);

        
        return view('xxx');
    }
}
```

When i open this in browser i get only "ImagickException" simple error.

[image: ImagickException]

I working on local, with:

- Laravel 8.54
- Windows 11
- XAMPP
- PHP Version 8.0.7

**phpinfo():**

- Compiler Visual C++ 2019
- Architecture x64
- imagick module version   3.5.1
- Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version    ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x64 2017-11-23
- Imagick using ImageMagick library version    ImageMagick 7.0.7-25 Q16
  x64 2018-03-04
- ImageMagick release date 2018-03-04
- ImageMagick number of supported formats: 240

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know the exact exception?  If not, then do you have Ghostscript installed? Does your ImageMagick policy restrict the use of PDF/PS/EPS files? Put the full path to Ghostscript as the preface to "gs" in the appropriate lines of the delegates.xml file in ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagick has a release candidate that fixes this error. We were experiencing the same issue after upgrading to Laravel 8.

The new release candidate was posted on 11/10/2021 (6 days after this post).
https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.6.0rc1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line of code:

```
if ($request->has('pdf_file')) 
        {
            $getPdfFile = $request->file('pdf_file');

            $originalname = $getPdfFile->getClientOriginalName();

            $path = $getPdfFile->storeAs('PdfToJpg', $originalname);
        }


        $storagePath = storage_path('app/PdfToJpg/' . $originalname);

         $imagick = new Imagick();

        $imagick->setResolution(600, 600);

        $imagick->readImage($storagePath);

        $imagick->writeImage(storage_path('app/PdfToJpg/download.jpeg'));
```

And,

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.00.0\bin
```

and rename `gswin64.exe` to `gs.exe`
And add Environment variables

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.00.0\bin
```

I run in php 7.4, Ghost script 10.0 and Imagick ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16 and laravel 7*
Thank you.